# Location globally defined in Chrome 13

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, window.location

I was using the Developer Tools in Chrome 13 when I typed this line:

```
var location = "Hello";
```

Upon pressing enter, the page changed and gave me a 404 error. The address bar now had `Hello` appended to the last address.

http://www.google.com/Hello

I swear that I have typed the exact same lines into Chrome in the past and not had the same problem. I thought location was at `window.location`.

Has something changed, or have I just never noticed this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly normal that the context in the developer tools would be `window`.  Type `this` and see what is says.  It's probably `window`.

Thus, when you type:

```
var location = "Hello";
```

You are trying to redefine a variable in the global scope that already exists.  The global scope in a browser is the `window` object.  Thus, `location` in the global scope is the same as `window.location`.

Trying to redefine an object that already exists (by using `var`) is not an error in javascript.  It just ignores the `var` declaration and does an assignment.  And, assigning a string to the location object, goes to a new web page.

Comment: Thinking about it now, that is very obvious.  I typed in this and, yes in fact, it was the window object.  I am just surprised I never noticed this before.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome may have changed its scoping rules.  It's unclear to me whether `var` on the console should be treated as window scope or some mysterious console scope.

If you want to create a variable named location, you should create a safe scope, for example by using an immediate function. E.g.

```
(function(){
  var location = "hello";  // safe
})();
```

Comment: It will execute in the global scope, and `location` already exists there. So it will rather overwrite `location`, which will cause a navigation. Just like `var foo = 123` will cause `window.foo === 123`.

Comment: Thanks @pimwdb, I thought so.  I couldn't remember if 13 worked that way or not since I stay on chromium latest all the time :/

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree that wrapping your code is the way to go.  Turns out jfriend00 was right in that the developer tools' context is window..

Comment: Yes, it seems that window is the default scope for chrome in general.  I had an old page on our internal system that created global variables (one of them called location) in a script block that worked fine in IE for years.  Opened it in Chrome and all went to hell.